# Container content changes proportion on window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The web page looks fine. However, when changing my browser window size, the content of the container is pushed up and down. Thus it either leaves a lot of container free space or just disappears (like it is under the next container).

[image]

But I would like it to always be inside the container with the same proportions.

Here is my code:

```css
  .first {
  padding-left: 5%;
  }

   .second {
       padding: 80px 50px 0px 70px;
       background-size: cover;
    }

    .fourth {
        margin-top: 7%;
    }

    .third {
     padding-top: 80px;
          padding-bottom: 65px;
          height: 678px;
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          min-height: auto;
          overflow-y: hidden;
          background: url("http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg");
          background-size: cover;
    }

    .selling-text {
        font-family: Ubuntu;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 27%;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }


    .second-block {
        background: #F2EADC;
        height: 500px;
         background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/824183-green-wallpaper.jpg");
         background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="third container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="device">
            <div class="screen">
                <!-- Demo image for screen mockup, you can put an image here, some HTML, an animation, video, or anything else! -->
                <img src="http://happybirthdaycakeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Yummy-Chocolate-Birthday-Cake.jpg" class="img-responsive first" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="second">
            <img src="http://gypsea.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/freeship.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="fourth">
                <button type="button" class="button  btn-block">MENU</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="second-block container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="screen">
            <p class="selling-text">
                See the best cake recipes.
                Trusted recipes for chocolate cake,
                white cake, banana cakes,
                and carrot cakes with photos and
                tips from home cooks.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 second">
        <div class="videoWrapper shadow">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JM_Q7HR55DY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't know why JSFiddle doesn't work with jQuery 1.11.1, it looks different from what I see connecting it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think that the problem is with the fixed height for your `<div class="third container-fluid">`, which has a height of 678px. To be more specific: as the columns move when you resize your window, the fixed height is becoming a problem because your container has less px than the combined height of your child elements - the col's.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27376/) where I have just commented out the fixed height

Comment: Oh, that's it! Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @LeraZemlyanaya I am glad I could help you out :) I guess it's one of those things that you do once and then remember